# Is it possible to send multiple values trough an URL with a checkbox form?

Tags: php, forms, post, get, categories

Hello I'd like to know if it is possible to do this?

i.e. i have this checkbox form:

```
<form action="c.php" method="get">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Filter Categories</legend>
    <p>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="id" value="1" name="catname" value="Music"/> Music</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="id" value="2 name="catname" value="Games"/> Games</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="id" value="3 name="catname" value="Tech"/> Tech</label>
    </p>
  </fieldset>
  <button type="submit">Filter</button>
  <button type="reset">Reset</button>
</form>
```

If i check ONLY music for example the url should look like this: http://domain.com/c.php?id=1&catname=Music

thanks

Comment: `name="catname[]"` for each of the names should do it

Answer (score 2):

Not with plain HTML. You can only have one attribute of a given name per element.

The best way to deal with this problem is to use a unique identifier as the value and then look up the various associated values on the server (e.g. using a database or hash table).

Alternatively, you could add structured data in the values (e.g. to have comma seperated values) and then parse them on the server.

You could also hack it using JavaScript by storing the additional data using `data-*` attributes and then using them to add and remove `<input type="hidden">` elements with appropriate names and values from the DOM when the checkbox is checked or unchecked.

(Note that to sensibly support multiple inputs with the same name in PHP, the names should end in `[]` so that it will populate `$_GET` with arrays instead of strings).